# Extract all text before, left of, the last number in a string

Tags: string, excel, extract

I need to removed all text to the left of the final number in my strings. Oddly, I can seem to find everything, but this. Here are examples of what I need.

Source:

1. OsteoActiv 150 Capsules
2. Vitamin B6 as Pyridoxal-5-Phosphate 33.8 mg 60 Vegetarian Capsules
3. Tyrosine 500 mg 60 Vegetarian Capsules
4. Green Tea-70 500 mg EGCG 350 mg 60 Vegetarian Capsules
5. Omega Supreme 90 Capsules

Result Needed:

1. 150 Capsules
2. 60 Vegetarian Capsules
3. 60 Vegetarian Capsules
4. 60 Vegetarian Capsules
5. 90 Capsules

[Excel-Extract-Text-Left-of-Final-Number-in-String.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTC6r.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

A UDF (aka *User Defined Function*) is best for custom parsing string of indeterminate length and structure. Paste the following into a module code sheet in the VBE.

```
Function udf_Last_Number_and_Unit(rng As Range)
    Dim tmp As String, v As Long, w As Long, vBITs As Variant

    vBITs = Split(rng.Value2, Chr(32))
    tmp = Join(vBITs, Chr(32))

    For v = LBound(vBITs) To UBound(vBITs)
        If IsNumeric(vBITs(v)) Then
            tmp = vbNullString
            For w = v To UBound(vBITs)
                tmp = Join(Array(tmp, vBITs(w)), Chr(32))
            Next w
        End If
    Next v

    udf_Last_Number_and_Unit = Trim(tmp)

End Function
```

Use like any native worksheet function.

[image: udf_last_number_and_unit]

Comment: So awesome. Thank you very, very much! May you have a wonderful year.